# Object reference not set to an instance of an object textBox

Tags: c#

Hello i need a help with my code here
Im really confused about this error,  i want to pass the value from textBox1 (form 1) to textBox7 (form 2).
and it said NullReferenceException was unhandled

**Form 1**

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            textBox1.Text = setIDtruk.getText;
            this.Close();
        }
        catch(Exception)
        {

            MessageBox.Show("Wrong");

        }
    }
```

**Form 2**

```
public string getText 
    {

        get
        {
            return textBox7.Text; // error in this statement
        }

    }
```

can anybody help me out ?
thanks

Comment: From which method do you get the exception?  B/c you should be catching the first.  Also, can you show us the textbox constructors?

Comment: @JohnYost `return textBox7.Text; // error in this statement`

Comment: Im sorry ,  really confuse here Form 1 http://www.2shared.com/document/hHvg2778/Form_1.html Form 2 http://www.2shared.com/document/vR2OiGub/Form_2.html if u dont dont mind can you help me to check my code thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you get a NullReferenceException on the line you indicate then the only reason that I can see is that `testBox7` is null.  We can't really tell you why it's null from the information that you've provided.

Answer (score 0):

If it says NullReferenceException was unhandled it's probably because your TextBox7 is null.
You might need to go through your code and see where you missed a declaration.

If having a null TextBox is part of your code logic, in that case instead of returning the textBox7.Text directly, test it for null and if it is (null) return the appropriate value instead (like an empty string).

Comment: I apologize for the lack of information from my explanation
Thanks for answering my question

if you don't mind, u can help to check my code here

this is my full code

Form 1
http://www.2shared.com/document/hHvg2778/Form_1.html

Form 2
http://www.2shared.com/document/vR2OiGub/Form_2.html

I still a beginner about c# programming

How do i test it ? don't know what to do about the code